# icinga2 check_cluster plugin and its implementation in 2.3+

Tags: linux, monitoring, icinga

it is not clear whether it was implemented in 2.3 version or it only will be?

```
/etc/icinga2/conf.d/commands.conf(52):  "-d" = ONDEMAND(*host1!PING,* service.state_id) + ", " + ONDEMAND(host2!PING, service.state_id)
```

**!** is prohibited  as I understood, and icinga2 warn me about this in startup.log .
Can we have a proper documentation and usage examples about this plugin in icinga 2.3+ ?
Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: https://dev.icinga.org/issues/7564#change-33960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've changed that into object accessor functions in a yet more generic way.

http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/advanced-topics#access-object-attributes-at-runtime

Comment: thanks, our company decided stay on nagios because it is too complicated  migrate existing configs to icinga2 + this magic language...

Comment: You should consider dropping the check_cluster plugin and use a more generic way to calculate states. Be it using business processes or check_multi or - a function to calculate the cluster state in icinga2's "magic" language. Migration isn't something which works 1:1 but requires desire to change things following the idea behind Icinga 2. Improve and change.